# How do I pass parameters after setting the content of a template?

Tags: kohana, parameter-passing

My problem is that I lose the parameters (i.e. I can't use the `id` variable) when I get inside the if condition because this occurs after I press the `submit` button in the view (i.e. after I set the post array)

```
public function action_resetpassword()
{
    $this->template->content = View::factory('user/password/reset')
    ->bind('message', $message)
    ->bind('errors', $errors);

    if (HTTP_Request::POST == $this->request->method()) 
    {           
        $id = $this->request->param('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you wish to pass parameters to the view which are set in the if. This can be done easily by 'binding' these variables to the view (i.e. pass by reference)

```
public function action_resetpassword()
{
    $this->template->content = View::factory('user/password/reset')
        ->bind('message', $message)
        ->bind('errors', $errors)
        ->bind('id', $id); // Empty variable is defined here ...

    if (HTTP_Request::POST == $this->request->method()) 
    {
        // ... and set here
        $id = $this->request->param('id');
```

Inside the view the `$id` will now have the value of whatever comes from the Request parameter.

If this is not what you mean, you should read a bit about variable scope in PHP and this question is not necessarily related to Kohana

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php